# Converting scad file format to stl in Python

Tags: python, file-conversion, openscad

Is there a way of converting SCAD files to STL format efficiently in Python? I have around 3000 files to be converted to STL. Plus, there are some different formats.

I tried searching on the internet for some libraries but was not able to find any suitable one (I am using Windows OS) Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Did you try solidpy?

Comment: Yes, but seems like you can not render to stl directly...

Comment: No idea then, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can run openscad from command line, see [documentation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/Using_OpenSCAD_in_a_command_line_environment),
and prepare every command by python (example in python3)

```
from os import listdir
from subprocess import call

files = listdir('.')
for f in files:
    if f.find(".scad") >= 0:            # get all .scad files in directory
        of = f.replace('.scad', '.stl') # name of the outfile .stl
        cmd = 'call (["openscad",  "-o", "{}",  "{}"])'.format(of, f)   #create openscad command
        exec(cmd)
```

in python3.5 and higher `subprocess.call` should be replaced by `subrocess.run()`

Comment: I have to add openscad to path first ?

Comment: there are some Windows notes under https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/Using_OpenSCAD_in_a_command_line_environment. But on windows 10 i don't get it working. On linux it's working quite well.

Comment: So I should call as openscad.exe isntead of openscad?

Comment: i tried `openscad`, `openscad.exe`, `openscad.com` and the same with full path without success. So i think its another question, how to run openscad from command line on windows.

Comment: oh ok, when I will get it run, I will mark this one as accepted, maybe others will come up with different ideas whileist